# How can I mount a fileshare into an azure container instance

Tags: azure, docker, cloud, volume, azure-container-instances

With docker-compose I can easily mount a local directory to a directory inside my container so I can persist some files. I'm currently experimenting with azure cloud and want to do the same thing as with docker-compose in the service azure container instances.

Since it would be too easy if Microsoft would adhere to this well-known syntax with its Azure service, container deployments in azure are defined using yml files or ARM templates.

**with docker-compose (works)**

```
volumes:
      - ./mnt/liferay/base:/etc/opt/liferay
```

**Azure container instance deployment file (.yml) (does not work)**

```
apiVersion: '2018-10-01'
location: westeurope
name: liferay
properties:
  containers:
  - name: liferay
    properties:
      image: xxxxxxx.azurecr.io/liferay-7.3.2ce:v1
      ports:
        - port: 80
        - port: 11311
      resources:
        requests:
          cpu: 2.0
          memoryInGB: 8.0
      volumeMounts:
      - mountPath: /mnt/liferay/base
        name: lrbase
      - mountPath: /lr-data
        name: lrdata
  osType: Linux
  restartPolicy: Always
  ipAddress:
    type: Public
    ports:
      - port: 80
    dnsNameLabel: xxxxxxx-liferay
  imageRegistryCredentials:
    - server: xxxxxxx.azurecr.io
      username: xxxxxxxdocker
      password: xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
  volumes:
  - name: lrbase
    azureFile:
      sharename: liferay
      storageAccountName: xxxxxxxstorage
      storageAccountKey: xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
  - name: lrdata
    azureFile:
      sharename: liferay
      storageAccountName: xxxxxxxstorage
      storageAccountKey: xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
tags: {}
type: Microsoft.ContainerInstance/containerGroups
```

Anybody knows what's wrong with my yml file ?

Comment: Any more questions? Does it solve your problem? If it works for you please accept it.

Comment: I don't get any response, also do not know if it solves your problem. Or you just want to get the solution without any response to the helper? Good luck later!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a common issue that one Azure File Share can only mount to one path, but you want to mount one file share to the two paths. That causes the problem. So I suggest you create another file share for another mount path.

Answer (score 0):

The file shares are mounted with "read only" rights.
Try to set the readOnly property to false within the AzureFile block (assuming you have problems writing to the shares, you should have precised the error message you were getting from the container logs).